# Use $compute on collection property in OData

Tags: odata

Given a model like

```
 public class Parent
 {
     [ Key ]
     public string Key { get;set; }
     public string ParentProp { get; set; }
     public List<Child> ManyChildren { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class Child
 {
     public string ChildName { get; set; }
     public int Value { get; set; }
 }
```

Where Child is a complex type so expand is not needed in this question.

I want to run a $compute function on each ChildName in the List, i cant figure out what the URL syntax would be.  I know if I want to $compute on the parent i can for example
`/odata/parents?$compute=substring(ParentProp,0,1) as FirstChar&$select=*` but I want to run the same substring on each ChildName in the List and preferably have the new property show up on the child in the response.